# How can I add tooltip to :before element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a problem with adding tooltip to :before element. For example my input become error and inside `<div class="form-group has-error">` is `:before` element that has icon. And I want to add with jQuery tooltip to this before element.

This is my code:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-input].has-error:before',
    animation: true,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'bottom',
    title: 'error message'
});
```

or this:

```
$('[data-input].has-error:before').on('hover', function () {
    $(this).tooltip({
        animation: true,
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'error message'
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: It may be a solution, try to insert an other dom element, for example div in "[data-input]. has-error: before" and inject tooltip code in!